# gnuplot: Increase gap between ylabel and ytics

Tags: plot, label, gnuplot

In gnuplotting, when I increase the font size of ylabel and ytics, they start to overlap. I tried to create margin between them, but couldn't find a solution. Would really appreciate the help in this regard.

```
      set   autoscale
      unset log
      unset label
      set xtic auto
      set ytic auto
      set tics font "Helvetica,18"
      set key font "Helvetica,18"
      set xlabel font "Helvetica,18"
      set ylabel font "Helvetica,18"

      set xlabel "Iteration Day"
      set ylabel "Number of Persons"

        set key inside
        set key right
        set key top

      plot  "SIR_I11_L2_T036.txt" using 1:2 title 'CurInf' with lines lt "5" lw "3", \
"SIR_I11_L2_T036.txt" using 1:3 title 'totInf' with lines lt "10" lw "3", \
"SIR_I11_L2_T036.txt" using 1:4 title 'Susceptible' with lines lt "15" lw "3", \
"SIR_I11_L2_T036.txt" using 1:5 title 'Exposed' with lines lt "20" lw "3", \
"SIR_I11_L2_T036.txt" using 1:7 title 'Recovered' with lines lt "25" lw "3"
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The argument is called `offset`. See `help xtics` and `help xlabels`

```
set xtics off 0,-2
set ytics off -4,0

set xlabel "Iteration Day" off 0,-4
set ylabel "Number of Persons" off 5,0
set bmargin 10

pl erf(0.3*x) t "recovered"
```

[image]

Comment: Had to use lmargin to adjust the y-axis spacing. Other than that, it worked perfect. thanks man.